# Delphi TQuery descendant object

Tags: delphi

I need to write a TQuery descendant with an override on onBeforePost event where I should check the state if its dsInsert or dsEdit or not... and allow or not the post to proceed, but I need someone with experience with custom components to double-check it.

It's been long since I created my components and I'm a bit rusty. Can you take a look at what I got and tell me if I am doing it right?

Here is my code for the component

```
unit MxQuery;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, DB, DBTables;

type
  TMxQuery = class(TQuery)
  procedure DoBeforePost; override;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

constructor TMxQuery.Create(AOwner:Tcomponent);
begin
 inherited create(AOwner);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMxQuery]);
end;

procedure TMxQuery.DoBeforePost;
begin
  case self.DataSource.State of
    dsEdit,dsInsert:
    begin
      //Do nothing or other stuff
    end;
    else
    begin
      self.DataSource.DataSet.Cancel;
      Abort;
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
end.
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks right to me. But why register it on designtime. it is a non visual component. Keep it at runtime

Comment: You mean: remove the register procedure and use the unit in other projects without having another Component on the pallette?

Comment: But the override, am I doing it properly? And the way I stop the query from posting seems right to you?

Comment: Well you raised the visibility from *protected* / *public* to **published**.

Comment: What is the point of the comments? Do you think that if a reader can't understand the word `private` the first time, that it will be clear the second time. Don't ever write comments that repeat what the code says. Such comments make your code worse. Why have empty sections? What's the point of empty private, protected, public sections?

Comment: I auto-generated the code (obviously) using Delphi GUI... (Component -> New Component) the class is generated automatically with all sections in order for me to fill them with my code... I like to do that because it nicely formats the code, I just keep the cleanup to the end of anything I do

Comment: What do you expect to prevent with this code? Other than dsInsert, dsEdit there is no events that require post.

Comment: It's interesting that you view programming as a task with a beginning and an end. To me, code is always changing.

Comment: Your code is absolutely unnecessary. `TDataSet` does not call `DoBeforePost` unless the dataset is already in `dsInsert` or `dsEdit` modes, so your code is a meaningless recheck. If `Post` is called on a dataset that is not in one of those states, an exception is raised and `DoBeforePost` never gets fired. (And if the dataset is *not* in one of those states, there's nothing for the dataset to `Cancel`, so your call to both `Cancel` and `Abort` are no ops - they serve no purpose.)

Comment: You are right Ken (and EProgrammerNotFound). I guess it's a proof of concept request

Comment: David, all programming is a never-ending process of continuing changes. However, I consider 'the end' as the first moment when my code is working well and is ready to deploy to the customer. I cannot disagree with your point of view :)

Comment: As mentioned before, your code won't work. Not due to incorrect component implementation, but a misunderstanding of `TDataSet` . Apart from that, it seems you're trying to guard against programmer mistake: _attempting to `Post` a data set that's not currently 'editing'_. You're trying to **hide** the programmer's **mistakes**. This is an absolute no-no bc eventually you'll have code full of **hidden mistakes**. Also from an OO design perspective, this is a terrible reason to subclass: you'd "fix" `TQuery` (only if you remember to create the subclass version) but what about `TADOQuery` et.al.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, this question fits https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ much better.

Anyway, let me point something out:

1. Your code should be working.
2. As @SirRufo said, you unnecessarily raised visibility of method `DoBeforePost` to `published`. Look for this this method in declaration `TQuery` or one of its ancestors. Override the method with the same visibility found there.
3. Constructor `TMxQuery.Create` is not needed, as it does not add anything.

Comment: I did not know about the site you mentioned. Thank you